# How to get started using Poco library?

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

I have the following [files](http://www.mediafire.com/?3ltrtzukcaps7a1)  which I currently just want to manage to compile successfully. I have looked for a tutorial on how to use [Poco](http://pocoproject.org/), but unfortunately I couldn't find one for a complete beginner (I tried to follow the docs both under linux & eclipse, and win & vs08.)

I would very much appreciate if someone could guide me through the correct use of the Poco library (either under eclipse or vs08.)

edit: found the problem, i didn't specify to the linker the exact libraries, only their search paths.

Comment: This seems too broad. It's better if you post the relevant code instead of a link to your source code. Then you can point out what problems you are having with your use of the library, and we can address a specific question.

Comment: i'll try to be more specific, lets say i want to use in my HelloWorld.cpp the following classes: Poco:DateTime::swap  & Poco::foo:foofigher. i really have no idea how to link\add the necessary files from the Poco library for my class to compile correctly. (this still might be a broad question, but again i really am clueless)

Answer (score 1):

You could look into how to use the POCO C++ as a static library in eclipse, then you first need to go through the process of building POCO for your architecture using make and the configure script included in the [POCO C++](http://pocoproject.org/download/index.html).

Next you should be able to find some tutorials on how to include static libraries (and headers) in eclipse VS.

There are plenty of sources on the internet. For example their [forum](http://pocoproject.org/forum/) and [this example](http://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~spl111/PracticalSession09_-_POCO_Examples)